# How to test for function return false?

Tags: vbscript

Can someone tell me what

```javascript
if(!IsNumeric(aNumber))
{
   do something
}
```

is in valid VBScript? I've tried

```vb
!IsNumeric(aNumber)
```

already.

Comment: What are you asking??  Are you getting an error?  What happened when you tried your code?

Comment: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ea'

Syntax error
Here:
/facts/process_homepage.asp, line 8

if !IsNumeric(pSessionVariableName)
---^

Comment: `!` is not valid operator in VBScript you should be using the [`Not` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cy86sfb(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical negation operator is called [Not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cy86sfb(v=vs.84).aspx) in VBScript:

```
>> b = 1 = 1
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(b), CStr(b), CStr(Not b)
>>
Boolean True False
>>
```

2nd sample:

```
>> For Each e In Split("1 a 2")
>>   If Not IsNumeric(e) Then
>>      WScript.Echo e, "not a number"
>>   Else
>>      WScript.Echo e, "a numerical string"
>>   End If
>> Next
>>
1 a numerical string
a not a number
2 a numerical string
>>
```